# Class APP\Http\ViewComposers\CompanyComposer does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new in laravel and I need some help with laravel 5. why do I get this error? The error is in Composer class and View conposer.
Here is error

[image]

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function boot()
     {
        View::composer(
            'index','APP\Http\ViewComposers\CompanyComposer'
        );
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class CompanyComposer
{
    /**
     *
     * @param View $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        //here is data
        $view->with('success', 'success');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your root namespace is `App` but you're asking for `APP`.